# how to fix height:auto css

Tags: html, css

On my website, I have created a menu bar at the bottom.  it is made from a div, with it's position:fixed.  It auto expands in case of viewing on a mobile device, but my problem is that it covers up the content if it's height expands.  My code looks something like the following, and I have a js-fiddle of my front website page so you can see exactly what I'm talking about.

```
div.navigation
{
position:fixed;
width:100%;
min-height:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dWU9P/

Comment: Using CSS only, your only option is to give the content a large enough padding–bottom, which will lead to unused blank space if the fixed div is less high. For a dynamic solution you’d have to use JS, to measure the actual height of the div and set the padding accordingly.

Comment: If the browser window is very small. like on a phone. You could use media-queries to make the menu smaller to make place for more content.

Comment: I don't mind using JS, if you could tell me how, @CBroe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put this in a comment, but I need 50 rep :(

Play around with:

`max-height:10%;`

It will stop it from expanding too high, you'll have to get your menu items to accommodate less menu space in some situations.